# How to apply multiple filters in a for loop for pyspark

Tags: python-2.7, loops, filter, pyspark, rdd

I am trying to apply a filter on several columns on an rdd. I want to pass in a list of indices as a parameter to specify which ones to filter on, but pyspark only applies the last filter.

I've broken down the code into some simple test cases and tried the non-looped version and they work.

```
test_input = [('0', '00'), ('1', '1'), ('', '22'), ('', '3')]

rdd = sc.parallelize(test_input, 1)
# Index 0 needs to be longer than length 0
# Index 1 needs to be longer than length 1
for i in [0,1]:
    rdd = rdd.filter(lambda arr: len(arr[i]) > i)

rdd.top(5)

# rdd.top(5) gives [('0', '00'), ('', '22')]
# Only 2nd filter applied
```

VS

```
test_input = [('0', '00'), ('1', '1'), ('', '22'), ('', '3')]

rdd = sc.parallelize(test_input, 1)
rdd = rdd.filter(lambda arr: len(arr[0]) > 0)
rdd = rdd.filter(lambda arr: len(arr[1]) > 1)

rdd.top(5)
# rdd.top(5) gives [('00', '00')] as expected
```

I expect the loop to give identical results compared to the non-looped version

Comment: It might related to closure: 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/rdd-programming-guide.html#understanding-closures